# NDK-build id not found in path

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I would like to install OpenCV4Android in my Windows7 Notebook and need to start with the tutorials part. I already have Eclipse (Java), SDK and ADT bundles installed.

I am following the link here's

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

While following the above link, I came to know that I Need to install NDK for OpenCV4Android.

I cameup with this [link] to install SDK

http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html

Somehow I followed the same in the above link. When I run the Project to know whether everything is working fine, I got the below error.

"\NDK-Build": launching failed
"/NDK_Build" is not found in PATH

I have followed all the other Posts in SO to overcome my error. But I haven't comeup with a better solution. Here's the glimpse of results from the other SO posts

I just wanted to start off with the sample tutorials of OpenCV4Android.

I stuck with NDK and was unable to sort out with the issue.

I went wrong somewhere and am dig in a well.

NOTE: I have screenshots of my project but unfortunately I can't post it over here as I don't have 10 Reputation score to post the Images.

Comment: Settingup the NDK Location

http://imgur.com/boFhzex

I have to set it until BUILD\ (If I copy the path until NDK\ it's returning the directory is invalid)

Using the ndk-buid.cmd in command prompt

http://i.imgur.com/4ppBSwf.png

Setting up the path in Environment variables 

http://i.imgur.com/YOPvSi9.png

Setting up with my SDK

http://i.imgur.com/zbVyoFK.png

I played with this too by pasting the path but no positive result (marked in red)

http://i.imgur.com/sc8Y3Qw.png

Comment: Please help me out!!!!